# Automate Excel COM AddIns

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

An Excel COM ADDIN was recently installed in all the computers at my workplace. So whenever someone tries to save a workbook, a pop-up is displayed and the users will have to select the classification of the workbook as **SensitiveInfo** or **NonSensitive** from the dropdown and then save.
Since we use lots of VBA macros, this COM ADDIN is creating a problem. So is there any way where AddIN can be automated to automatically select a classfication from the dropdown.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: seems like this may depend on the actual add-in in question.
Was it developed in house, or is it something that is commercially available?

Comment: It was developed in house..

Comment: I would think it's pretty likely that the add-in is intercepting a BeforeSave event at the application level, so you could try just disabling events in the code, saving then re-enabling events and see if the add-in still prompts you.